# EF Core 3.1 re-inserting existing navigational property when adding new entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am adding a new entity to the DbContext with a navigational property passed from the client but instead of EF recognising that the navigational property entity already exist, it tries to re-insert it which fails because you cannot have duplicate primary keys.

```
var profile = _mapper.Map<Profile>(profileDto);
profile.User.LockoutEnabled = true;
profile.User.Password = new PasswordHasher<User>().HashPassword(profile.User, "*********");
profile.Company = null; // Doing this works fine but otherwise it fails.

await _dataContext.Set<Profile>().AddAsync(profile);
await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        
profile.Company = await _dataContext.Set<Company>().FindAsync(profile.CompanyId);

return _mapper.Map<ProfileCreateDto>(profile);
```

Since nulling the Company entity or changing the client to pass only the CompanyId instead of the Company value works fine, I still want to understand why EF is try to re-insert an existing entity.

Comment: Looks like the context sees the parent as created. I doubt change tracking passes through the wire as it's the server side context only that tracks it. You could try to manually set the parent entity stage to "unchanged".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is trying to re-insert the `Company` entity because you are using the `AddAsync` method to insert your `Profile` entity.

The `AddAsync` method causes the entity in question (`Profile`) and all it's related entities (e.g. `Company`) present in the entity-graph to be marked as `Added`. An entity marked as `Added` implies - `This is a new entity and it will get inserted on the next SaveChanges call.` See details - [`DbSet<TEntity>.AddAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addasync?view=efcore-5.0).

As a general solution, in a disconnected scenario, when creating new entity with an entity-graph (with one or more related entities) use the `Attach` method instead.

The `Attach` method causes any entity to be marked as `Added` only if it doesn't have the primary-key value set. Otherwise, the entity is marked as `Unchanged`. An entity marked as `Unchanged` implies - `This entity already exists in the database and it might get updated on the next SaveChanges call.` See details - [`DbSet<TEntity>.Attach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.attach?view=efcore-5.0)

I hope that meets your curiosity.

Comment: Thanks @atiyar, Attach is what I needed to use and now I'll be able to clean all the entity.navproperty = null;